# Separating column separated cells into one column that corresponds to parent column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've been given a table that is a real mess and I need help cleaning up some of the data in it.

The fields are grouped by Region, District, and then Store. Each store number should have it's own new row. 
This is what the table looks like now:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ Region ║   District    ║         Store          ║
╠════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ West   ║ N. California ║ 1, 2, 5, 8, 22, 23, 32 ║
║ West   ║ S. California ║ 6, 7, 9, 12, 15        ║
║ East   ║ E. New York   ║ 18, 26, 27, 54, 88     ║
╚════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

This is what I need it to look like:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ Region ║   District    ║ Store ║
╠════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╣
║ West   ║ N. California ║     1 ║
║ West   ║ N. California ║     2 ║
║ West   ║ N. California ║     5 ║
║ West   ║ N. California ║     8 ║
║ West   ║ N. California ║    22 ║
║ West   ║ N. California ║    23 ║
║ West   ║ N. California ║    32 ║
║ West   ║ S. California ║     6 ║
║ West   ║ S. California ║     7 ║
╚════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

I have a macro that does take all the store numbers and puts them into one column, but it does not take into consideration the Region/District columns. The macro simply puts all numbers into one column.
Here is the macro I used:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim fromCol As String
    Dim toCol As String
    Dim fromRow As String
    Dim toRow As String
    Dim inVal As String
    Dim outVal As String
    Dim commaPos As Integer

    ' Copy from column A to column B.'
    fromCol = "F"
    toCol = "H"
    fromRow = "1"
    toRow = "1"

    ' Go until no more entries in column A.'
    inVal = Range(fromCol + fromRow).Value
    While inVal <> ""

        ' Go until all sub-entries used up.'
        While inVal <> ""
            Range(fromCol + fromRow).Select

            ' Extract each subentry.'
            commaPos = InStr(1, inVal, ",")
            While commaPos <> 0

                ' and write to output column.'
                outVal = Left(inVal, commaPos - 1)
                Range(toCol + toRow).Select
                Range(toCol + toRow).Value = outVal
                toRow = Mid(Str(Val(toRow) + 1), 2)

                ' Remove that sub-entry.'
                inVal = Mid(inVal, commaPos + 1)
                While Left(inVal, 1) = " "
                    inVal = Mid(inVal, 2)
                Wend
                commaPos = InStr(1, inVal, ",")
            Wend

            ' Get last sub-entry (or full entry if no commas).'
            Range(toCol + toRow).Select
            Range(toCol + toRow).Value = inVal
            toRow = Mid(Str(Val(toRow) + 1), 2)
            inVal = ""
        Wend

        ' Advance to next source row.'
        fromRow = Mid(Str(Val(fromRow) + 1), 2)
        Range(fromCol + fromRow).Select
        inVal = Range(fromCol + fromRow).Value
    Wend
End Sub
```

Can anyone assist in providing me a more effective way of doing this? 
I'd really appreciate any help!

Edit:
Here is my actual table. The above was just as an example.

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Region    ║ District             ║ Stores                                                                 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Arizona North        ║ 13, 168, 179, 309, 379, 391, 440, 455, 528, 608, 663, 675              ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Arizona South        ║ 35, 36, 37, 218, 252, 302, 447, 510, 535, 545                          ║
║ WEST      ║ Bay Area             ║ 17, 19, 38, 205, 268, 284, 349, 361, 362, 386, 476, 494, 591, 601, 638 ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ Central Florida      ║ 108, 133, 189, 228, 354, 366, 454, 485, 492, 565, 667, 676             ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Central Texas        ║ 69, 94, 183, 195, 248, 285, 318, 385, 491, 512, 622                    ║
║ WEST      ║ Central Valley       ║ 4, 7, 9, 16, 241, 450, 490, 516, 600                                   ║
║ EAST      ║ Chicago              ║ 126, 178, 187, 295, 418, 427, 497, 543, 669, 693                       ║
║ NORTHEAST ║ Connecticut          ║ 260, 273, 306, 307, 312, 321, 341, 367, 396, 398, 473, 585, 661        ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ Crystal Coast        ║ 82, 87, 91, 191, 327, 352, 589, 593, 609, 627, 633                     ║
║ NORTHEAST ║ Detroit              ║ 117, 143, 145, 153, 170, 210, 235, 320, 407, 458, 522, 588, 660        ║
║ EAST      ║ East Pennsylvania    ║ 139, 140, 151, 159, 162, 164, 261, 328, 329, 344, 513                  ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ Florida East         ║ 128, 150, 163, 436, 466, 536, 538, 648, 655                            ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ Georgia/Alabama      ║ 95, 106,110, 148, 350, 353, 364, 486, 546, 570, 582, 616, 689          ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Heartland            ║ 74, 75, 76, 186, 239, 258, 388, 574, 619, 624                          ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Houston East         ║ 83, 193, 197, 247, 324, 378, 493, 617                                  ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Houston West         ║ 71, 79, 172, 246, 254, 323, 372, 431, 460, 483, 547, 680               ║
║ WEST      ║ Inland Empire        ║ 26, 28, 31, 33, 380, 384, 404, 464, 523, 525, 580, 592, 636, 654       ║
║ EAST      ║ Long Island          ║ 337, 347, 368, 375, 376, 390, 403, 430, 521                            ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Louisiana            ║ 80, 81, 90, 100, 272, 275, 336, 508, 511, 576, 631                     ║
║ NORTHEAST ║ Michigan             ║ 152, 157, 188, 265, 308, 428, 437, 446, 479, 583, 628, 630, 664        ║
║ EAST      ║ Mid America          ║ 114, 134, 135, 142, 280, 358, 400, 424, 471, 475, 481, 503, 670        ║
║ EAST      ║ Mid Atlantic         ║ 161, 166, 175, 177, 181, 206, 315, 413, 448, 451, 489, 568, 595        ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Minnesota/Wisconsin  ║ 88, 132, 137, 156, 212, 219, 253, 271, 356, 359, 482, 488, 612         ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ N Carolina East      ║ 101, 104, 120, 220, 240, 264, 269, 276, 335, 369, 563, 632, 682        ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ N Carolina West      ║ 99, 192, 208, 299, 434, 505, 529, 610, 618, 671, 677, 685              ║
║ NORTHEAST ║ New England          ║ 298, 338, 342, 345, 351, 405, 409, 439, 442, 465, 467, 478             ║
║ EAST      ║ New Jersey           ║ 176, 182, 199, 201, 215, 281, 326, 393, 397, 432, 537                  ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ New Mexico           ║ 55, 56, 65, 67, 70, 72, 236, 402, 417, 443, 586, 691                   ║
║ NORTHEAST ║ New York East        ║ 154, 173, 196, 334, 355, 517, 639, 646, 662                            ║
║ NORTHEAST ║ New York West        ║ 147, 149, 158, 233, 245, 487, 641, 643, 647                            ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ North Florida        ║ 107, 115, 138, 213, 238, 294, 325, 435, 449, 468, 566, 668             ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ North Indiana        ║ 111, 113, 116, 222, 224, 229, 234, 438, 441, 573                       ║
║ EAST      ║ North Jersey         ║ 237, 293, 340, 343, 365, 381, 389, 395, 420, 421, 524                  ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ North Texas          ║ 53, 61, 73, 167, 185, 311, 317, 422, 502, 575, 635, 657                ║
║ EAST      ║ Ohio North           ║ 121, 123, 130, 160, 202, 221, 249, 461, 484, 584, 594                  ║
║ EAST      ║ Ohio South           ║ 112, 119, 180, 231, 232, 423, 549, 550                                 ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Ohio Valley          ║ 1, 25, 122, 125, 184, 211, 262, 274, 305, 410, 518, 604                ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Oklahoma             ║ 48, 63, 64, 66, 251, 267, 357, 360, 462, 472, 590                      ║
║ WEST      ║ Orange County        ║ 12, 20, 27, 29, 34, 373, 401, 414, 425, 433, 571, 526, 605             ║
║ WEST      ║ Portland             ║ 30, 39, 40, 45, 46, 169, 243, 255, 278, 429, 452, 477, 581             ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Rocky Mountain North ║ 58, 59, 68, 77, 136, 230, 263, 266, 603, 673                           ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Rocky Mountain South ║ 62, 171, 174, 203, 314, 394, 419, 498, 500, 620, 696                   ║
║ WEST      ║ Sacramento/Nevada    ║ 11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 204, 310, 383, 540, 614, 656, 659                  ║
║ WEST      ║ San Diego            ║ 8, 14, 15, 18, 42, 226, 348, 411, 412, 444, 445, 506, 515              ║
║ WEST      ║ San Fernando         ║ 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 32, 200, 217, 374, 459, 572, 602, 681                  ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ South Carolina       ║ 96, 103, 129, 209, 223, 319, 331, 532, 606, 634, 645, 651, 672         ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ South Florida        ║ 124, 131, 146, 282, 316, 346, 501, 504, 519, 644, 649                  ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ South Texas          ║ 57, 60, 198, 225, 257, 259, 297, 371, 426, 463, 613                    ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ St. Louis            ║ 78, 92, 93, 127, 155, 194, 242, 290, 304, 370, 415, 534, 679           ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Tennessee East       ║ 84, 86, 89, 118, 214, 270, 301, 303, 495, 587, 611, 623, 653           ║
║ MIDWEST   ║ Tennessee West       ║ 85, 286, 287, 289, 406, 640, 642, 652                                  ║
║ SOUTHWEST ║ Utah                 ║ 41, 43, 44, 54, 105, 292, 332, 333, 363, 480, 520, 569                 ║
║ EAST      ║ Virginia East        ║ 97, 102, 109, 244, 300, 322, 416, 626                                  ║
║ EAST      ║ Virginia West        ║ 98, 227, 313, 514, 527, 625                                            ║
║ WEST      ║ Washington North     ║ 52, 207, 279, 330, 339, 377, 530, 621, 629, 690                        ║
║ WEST      ║ Washington South     ║ 47, 49, 50, 51, 190, 296, 392, 453, 457, 533, 596, 674                 ║
║ SOUTHEAST ║ West Florida         ║ 141, 144, 165, 256, 283, 399, 456, 469, 470, 474, 509, 665             ║
║ EAST      ║ West Pennsylvania    ║ 216, 250, 277, 288, 291, 408, 496, 531, 541, 564, 567, 615             ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: What happened to 9, 12 and 15?

Comment: The numbers refer to a specific location. For instance, Store #1, Store #2, etc. The tables above only represent a small portion of my data.

Comment: I suggest adding it to your example because as is, it suggests that somehow some of the stores are dropped. I think you could do this with an array then add rows from that.

Comment: Split the comma separated store list into commas. Depending on your version of Excel, you could use Power Pivot or the Get & Transform tab on the Data ribbon to create a query that would unpivot the store column and produce what you want.

Comment: Ok added my table in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim iRegion As Long, iRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stores") '<== change it as per your needs
        With .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, 3) 'I'm assuming that "Region" is column "A", "District" is column "B" and "Store" is column "C"
            myArr = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
        For iRegion = LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)
            With .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Split(myArr(iRegion, 3), ",")) + 1)
                .Offset(, 0) = myArr(iRegion, 1)
                .Offset(, 1) = myArr(iRegion, 2)
                .Offset(, 2) = Application.Transpose(Split(myArr(iRegion, 3), ","))
            End With
        Next iRegion
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This might work. My table actually has 58 rows of data, not just 3. How would I adjust this to work for the whole table?

Comment: Assuming you're speaking of 58 "columns" (not "rows"), the adjustment is up to the actual "structure" of the data: is column "C" the one with "Stores" to be listed and all other columns with data to be simply repeated?

Comment: Ok I added in my actual table to reference. Your macro was only running on the first 3 regions, not the entire list.

Comment: sorry: I was using `LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)` instead of `LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)`.  see edited answer

Comment: This is it! Thank you soooo much!